# Why execute permisiions along with write permissions needed for creating file in c(Linux)?

Tags: c, linux, file-permissions

I am trying to create a file from my c source code on linux. I am using `dd` command for reading from a file and writing in to a file by creating there. If i don't have execute permissions(I have write permissions) for target directory(Where the file is going to be created), It is unable to create file. If I have both write and execute permissions, It is able to create file. What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is probably off topic for this site, but in a directory "x" doesn't mean execute, but permission to access the files in the directory. This in contrast to "r", which just gives permission to see the names of the files.

Comment: Can you tell me where should i post this question?

Comment: @Chinna : You can post it [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). Well anyways, I think you have already got your answer.